# Capture multiple images with camera, after a single 'button press'?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, camera

Basically, through the use of a custom overlay with the camera app, I am wanting multiple images (in my case 5) to be taken, with only one press of a 'capture' button.

I understand that the following code:

```
- (void)takePicture:(id)sender
{
    self.pictureButton.enabled = NO;
    [self.delegate takePicture];
}
```

results in a single image being taken. Is there a way to have this action replicated 5 times, after a single button press? Effectively, this would achieve a 'burst' like effect, as is implemented in the Camera+ app.

Comment: You can use an NSTimer with repeat set to YES to fire a UIImagePickerController's takePicture method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code it take 5 pictures from camera and store in an array. use as you need.

```
int counter;
NSMutableArray * imageArray;

-(void)takePicture
 {
       counter=0;
       UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
}

 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
UIImage *image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

[imageArray addObject:image];
counter++;  
if (counter<5)
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:NO];
    [imagePicker release];
}
else
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

}
```