# can I capture 5 consecutive pictures in 1 second just one click in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the below code for clicking 5 consecutive images in just 1 click but i am unable to do this. what should I do?

```
- (IBAction)cameraaBtton:(id)sender 
{
  for ( int i=0;1<5; i++)
  {
   [self CapturePhoto];
   }
}
```

and the capture photo method is:

```
- (void)CapturePhoto
{

imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Device has no camera" message:@"Dear user please buy a apple cell" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alertview show];
```

}

Comment: see this once may be it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806235/capture-multiple-images-with-camera-after-a-single-button-press

Comment: Sir in this,why for loop is not executing?

Comment: the reason your view is already presneted , try this before present the new view dismiss the previous view

Comment: thank You  sir. Sir if I want take 5 pics in 1 second then should I use NSTimer or anything else!

Comment: Sir this is not working in my phone..